# Remove invalid tags with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to remove some invalid tags/html with jquery, but I think because its invalid the selector cant find it. IE

```html
<p>Here1 is <a href="" class="tooltipster">Here is lots of text in page <a href="" class="tooltipster">REMOVE THIS</a> more content</a> and its cool</p>
```

```js
$("a").find("a").remove();
```

Nothing happens, however if I change the second a (invalid one) to a span the selector can find and remove it? Thanks

======================================================

Update, ive taken m69s regex and added it to jquery (elements not in DOM so I cant use getelementbyID)

```js
 $(.container p).each(function (index) {

            var cont = $(this).html().match(/^(.*?<A[^>]+>.*?)<A[^>]+>.*?(<\/A>.*)$/i);
            if (cont) $(this).html(cont[1] + cont[2]);

 });
```

Comment: The HTML you're trying to change has already been parsed into DOM; it doesn't exist anymore. Ultimately you'll have to fix it at the source, or see how the DOM looks like and whether it's possible to modify it there.

Comment: `more content/a>`  is this a typo, or it's actually like this ? shouldn't it be `more content</a>`?

Comment: Totally agree... by the time it's sent to the browser it's too late

Comment: Please dont do that. I bet it is far easier to fix this in the source of the problem.

Comment: content is actually not in the dom yet, html is in a javascript var - just wanted to use the jquery selector functions on it, that make a difference?

Comment: @cerls not really, jQuery uses dom parser from browser so html needs to be valid. Can't throw a band-aid on the real problem being whatever source it is

Comment: Getting the innerHTML of the surrounding P element almost gets you there, but the second closing tag is missing. So you can remove the complete illegal A tag, but you have to guess where the legal closing A tag should be.

Comment: sorry broken second tag is typo - should be proper tag just invalidly nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes the illegal A element, but it doesn't completely restore the legal A element, because the browser removes the second closing A tag. As a result, some text that was inside the link may now come after it. (If you want to avoid the link being empty, you could move the next word into it.)

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var cont = elem[i].innerHTML.match(/^(.*?<A[^>]+>.*?)<A[^>]+>.*?(<\/A>.*)$/i);
    if (cont) elem[i].innerHTML = cont[1] + cont[2];
}
```

```html
<p>A simple text paragraph.</p>
<p>A paragraph with <a href="">a legal <a href="">ILLEGAL LINK</a> link</a> and some more text.</p>
<p>A paragraph with <a href="">a legal link</a> and some more text.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks m69 that worked! I actually made a jquery version of it using each() - ill update the op

Answer (score 0):

Save your file as xhtml, the browser should find the un-closed tags for you. I don't think there is a way that this could be done in javascript.